# Mapping legacy tables and multiple hasMany associations

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am attempting to map a few legacy (existing) tables to my domain objects.
So far with a single 1:n mapping it has worked rather well. I have an ITEM or YFS_ITEM table which maps to  an Item_Alias (YFS_ITEM_ALIAS) table (OmsItemAlias). My objects look are shown below for the associations.

When I create or do a find on OmsItem I do indeed get back OmsItemAlias objects. The problem comes in when I look for inventoryItems for some reason this is always 0, even though I know there are items which exist in the database.

```
package com.fheg.orderrouter

class OmsItem {

String id
String item
String description
Double unitCost
String defaultProductClass
String organizationCode

static hasMany = [ aliases : OmsItemAlias,inventoryItems : InventoryItem]


static constraints = {
  id(blank: false, nullable: false)
  item(nullable: false)
  description(nullable: false)
  unitCost(nullable: false)
  defaultProductClass(nullable: false)
  organizationCode(nullable: false)
}


static mapping = {
  table 'YFS_ITEM'
  version false

  id  column:'ITEM_KEY', generator:'assigned', sqlType: 'char(24)'
  item column: 'ITEM_ID', sqlType: 'char(40)'
  description(column: 'DESCRIPTION', sqlType: 'varchar2(500)')
  unitCost column: 'UNIT_COST', sqlType: 'NUMBER(19,6)'
  defaultProductClass column: 'DEFAULT_PRODUCT_CLASS',sqlType: 'char(10)'
  organizationCode column: 'ORGANIZATION_CODE', sqlType: 'char(24)'
  aliases(sort:'aliasName', fetch: 'eager')
  inventoryItems( fetch: 'eager')
 }
}
```

Here is the code for InventoryItem.

```
package com.fheg.orderrouter

class InventoryItem {

String id
String organizationCode
String uom
String productClass

static belongsTo = [ invItem : OmsItem ]
static hasMany = [ inventorySupply : InventorySupply]



static constraints = {
    id(blank: false, nullable: false)
    organizationCode(nullable: false)
//        invItem(nullable: false)
    uom(nullable: false)
    productClass(nullable: false)
}



static mapping = {
    table 'YFS_INVENTORY_ITEM'
    version false

    id  column:'INVENTORY_ITEM_KEY', generator:'assigned'
    invItem column: 'ITEM_ID'
    organizationCode column: 'ORGANIZATION_CODE'
    uom column: 'UOM'
    productClass column:'PRODUCT_CLASS'


   }

}
```

I am quite sure what I am doing wrong with regard to the belongTo/hasMany. It works fine for the aliases, but does nothing for inventoryItems. Any suggestions is are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I can see.

I don't think `fetch: 'eager'` is a valid fetch type: [see Fetch](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/fetch.html)

what you might want is: `lazy: false` , [see Fetching](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#fetching)

Now also I think you might want a join and not selects, so maybe (this I can't guarantee is totally correct but I hope puts u on the right track):

```
inventoryItems column: 'ITEM_ID', ignoreNotFound: true, fetch: 'join'
```

and in the InventoryItem mapping:

```
invItem column: 'ITEM_ID'
```

Now maybe turn on Hibernate logging to see what is going on at the SQL level

In Config.groovy find the log4j setup and add:

```
trace 'org.hibernate.SQL'
```

Also see [FAQ](http://grails.org/FAQ#Q%3a%20How%20can%20I%20turn%20on%20logging%20for%20hibernate%20in%20order%20to%20see%20SQL%20statements,%20input%20parameters%20and%20output%20results?)

on top of that you turn on SQL logging on a [per datasource](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource) setting

...or even try the [P6 plugin](http://www.grails.org/p6spy+plugin) if necessary, that should give you more of a hint as to what SQL is being generated

Sorry for the reference overkill